# Need to extend Audience manager database

Tags: audience-manager

Can we add new column in any table of Audience manager database and also need to add more tables in Audience manager database,

We need to add few more contacts from some custom form and for that we need to extend columns and tables in Audience manager database, these new users later in future also will be going to used as the subscribed users so that they can get the newsletter from CMS outbound mailing subsciption.

So extending AM database is the right approach or do we need to create seprate database for those new contacts.

Answer (score 5):

The "Custom Contact Extended Details" table is designed to be extended by the implementation team, and this is the suggested method to add your own fields to contacts.

The Documentation (login required) [covers this](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-E4596A79-2FD5-43DF-9BA9-F6B304D3EFAF) in quite some extensive detail.

In a nutshell you need to:

- Create the fields you need in the databases (need both CM and CD tables to be changed with *exactly* the same fields)
- Configure the Content Manager to "understand" these new fields by defining them in `OutboundEmail.xml`

Comment: and also sync b/w CMS's AM DB and CD's AM DB- will happen without any hurdle in case of updated fields

Comment: As long as the fields match, sync will not be a problem.

Comment: This is also the *only* database changes you are allowed to do. Don't add new columns or tables into the database. If you cannot get by using the Extended Details, you'd need to store your data elsewhere.

Comment: @Peter : Our requirement here is to add login details of user into database so that those users could also get the newsletter from Outbound mail, hence for that we might need to add few more columns for storing addition inof of users and also need to add new table for additin some additional info for roles.

Comment: The login details sound like they could be Extended Details (don't forget to encrypt them); but I assume the roles can be multiple rows, so you'd need to store that in another database.